# NVM: How do you set the node version globally?

Tags: javascript, npm, nvm

When using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), I can set the version of node to the latest version in the current directory with `nvm use node`. How do you specify which version to use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's say you have versions `v8.2.0` and `v8.3.0` installed.

To make version `v8.2.0` the currently used one, you can call `nvm use 8.2.0`.

`nvm use` also accepts aliases, so you could create one like this:
`nvm alias mysuperversion 8.2.0` and then make it the current one by calling `nvm use mysuperversion`.

To make a specific version of Node a **global** one, you should create a `default` alias (or modify it if it already exists, the same way you create a new one).

Comment: Example of setting the default (globally): `nvm alias default v15.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

`nvm use VERSION`

if VERSION is 12.22.6, the command to use this version is

`nvm use 12.22.6`

You must install a version before using it. To install a version, the command is:

`nvm install VERSION`

If you wish to alias your versions, then you would use the command:

```
nvm alias mynodeversion 12.22.6
nvm use mynodeversion
```